# How do I create a GitHub Action that will enforce a Pull Request is rebased on the latest master before merging?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I want developers in a repository to have to manually rebase feature branches on master. Developers should then fix conflicts and test before a final push and merge to master. Ideally I could have code behind the "Merge" button on GitHub that would:

1. Lock master
2. Verify that the base of the pull request's branch is exactly the commit at the head of master
3. Merge the pull request's branch to master
4. Unlock master

I don't believe this is at all how Github Actions work. Maybe I could run an action that can compare the PR's base to master's HEAD, failing the check run if they are not identical. This action would need to run on every push to each PR's branch and every push to master, but with a separate check run executed for each open PR.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not just require branches to be up to date using https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-a-branch-protection-rule? Or find out why people aren't already doing this, rather than making a robot force them.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try using that setting - it seems like it could do everything I need.